# Computing the class group of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible polynomial.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

As the title says, I am wanting to compute the class group of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is the real root of the irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^3+2x^2+6x+6.$

Denoting by $K$, the field $\mathbb{Q}/(f)$, I have previous determined that $O_K=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

The Minkowski bound for $O_K$ is less than 7, so I factorise $f(x)$ modulo the primes 2, 3 and 5.

- Modulo 2, $f(x)$ factorises as $x^3$, so $<2>=<2,\alpha>^3$
- Modulo 3, $f(x)$ factorises as $x^2(x+2)$, so $<3>=<3,\alpha>^2<3,\alpha+2>$
- Modulo 5, $f(x)$ factorises as $(x-1)(x^2 - 2x - 1)$, so $<5>=<5,\alpha - 1><5,\alpha^2 - 2\alpha - 1>$

I've found that the norm of $\alpha+1$ is $3$, so this means that $<3,\alpha>$ and$ <3,\alpha+2>$ are principal.

Also, the norm of $\alpha+2$ is $10=2\cdot5$. Is this enough to conclude that the class group is isomorphic to $C_3$?

Thanks.

Comment: Remember that the class group is generated by the prime ideals whose norm is at most the Minkowski bound, so in your case the ideal above 2, the ones above 3 and the one above 5 which has norm 5, namely $(5,\alpha-1)$. Now you have to look for relations between ideals. For example, since $\alpha$ has norm $6$ (recall that the norm is the constant term of the minimal polynomial), by unique factorization you must have $(\alpha)=(2,\alpha)(3,\alpha)$. To look for elements of small norm, you can try to check $\alpha-1$ or $\alpha+1$, this kind of things.

Comment: Bear in mind that if $f(a) = 0$ in any field, then $(X-a) \mid f(X)$. The fact that you have found a root of $f$ modulo $5$ proves that it cannot be irreducible.

Comment: @Mathmo123 That's what I was confused about. I couldn't find a quadratic that multiplies by $x-\alpha$ to get $f(x)$

Comment: The product of $X-a$ and the quadratic won't be equal to $f(X)$ in $\mathbb Z[X]$ unless $f$ itself is reducible. They just have to be equal modulo $5$. Just follow through factorising as you would normally, but be prepared for this nuance.

Comment: @Mathmo123 Can't believe I missed that haha. Okay so $x^3 + 2x^2 + 6x + 6=(x-1)(x^2 - 2x - 1)$ mod $5$.

Comment: @Ferra Can you check my answer now?